# Kubuntu 13.04 Blutooth missing from system settings!

Tags: 13.04, kubuntu, kde, bluetooth

I have a strange problem.  I no longer see any Bluetooth settings in the Kubuntu System Settings.

I'm running Kubuntu 13.04 x64, kernel 3.10.9.  My Bluetooth device is working.  I can see it remotely, and I can test it using various utilities.  (Such as from bluez-utils.)

However, there are no longer any Bluetooth settings **anywhere** in the Kubuntu System Settings!

I haven't removed any Bluetooth packages, at least, not knowingly!

I'm at a complete loss as to how this could happen, where the settings are supposed to be, or what could cause them to disappear in the first place!

The Bluetooth adapter is an Atheros AR3012.  One thing I'm confused about is the driver for this device.  Based on the entries in the kernel, I would have thought that the driver would be the 'hci_uart' module, however, the driver is really the 'btusb' module.

Regardless, as I said, it's working.  I just can't control it from within KDE, because the settings are simply **gone**!

Please help!  Thanks!  :-)

***Edit:***  I should add that doing a search for Bluetooth in the System Settings tool returns nothing, nor does searching in the KDE menu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the package `bluedevil` installed ?

`bluedevil` is:

```
Description: KDE Bluetooth stack
 BlueDevil is a set of components which integrate Bluetooth in KDE.
 It contains:
  * A KDE Control Module (KCM) to configure all the Bluetooth-related options.
  * Integration with the KDE input/output system (KIO), which allows you to
    discover and explore Bluetooth devices from your favorite file browser.
  * A wizard to pair your devices and connect directly to services they offer,
    such as input (mouse, keyboard, Wiimote) and audio (headsets, phones).
  * A system tray application from where all BlueDevil actions can be done
    (disconnect devices, send files, configure, etc...)
  * A daemon to listen incoming requests, for example to receive files
    or to introduce a requested PIN.
Homepage: https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/base/bluedevil
```

To check if it is installed (replace `kcmshell4` with `kcmshell5` on KDE Plasma5):

```
:~$ kcmshell4 --list | grep blue
bluedeviladapters          - Configure the available Bluetooth adapters
bluedevildevices           - Configure the known Bluetooth remote devices
bluedeviltransfer          - Configure the Bluetooth receive files
```

To install it; simply run:

```
sudo apt install bluedevil
```

Comment: Eureka!  Thank you SO much!  :-)  Now I'd like to figure out how it got UN-installed!  I certainly didn't purposefully remove it, and I'm the only person with access to this system.  Only thing I can think of is possibly when I did an 'apt-get autoremove'!